# C++: Extend already created C struct with custom hash and equal functions to be usable in unordered_map

Tags: c++

I have two projects, one is written in C and the other one in C++. I need to use a C-struct in my C++ program in a unordered_map. How can I extend the struct by a hash and compare function such that I don't always have to pass those functions to the unordered_map?

Comment: Do you mean using the C struct as a key in unordered_map? The using directive is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `==` operator outside the struct (that’s allowed) and specialize `std::hash` for your struct in a C++ file. See an example at cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash